# How to debug x64 with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, debugging, 64-bit

I'm trying to create my first Silverlight application. It seems that it can't be debugged because Visual Studio 2010 uses the x86 'Remote Debugger'. It that I also have the x64 bit version installed in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64
```

But I can't find how I'm supposed to make VS 2010 use

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64
```

instead of

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86
```

Thank you.

Comment: don't know how to solve your issue, but i can say that I develop silverlight apps with vs2010 on a 64 bit machine and I can debug without having done anything special. I think Silverlight apps are always 32 bit anyway. Maybe check properties.

Comment: Thank you. The only solution I found so far is to set Internet Explorer as default browser, then I can you the "Start Debugging (F5)" function of VS2010. But what I would like to do is to debug it as an IIS application ("attach to process")